# Chrome Set Cross Domain Cookie

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, cookies, web

My site is a.com and I want to create a cookie in b.com.

I try to set a cross domain cookie using an ajax request to b.com and returning a set cookie header. 
If I go directly to b.com the cookie is set, but it doesn't set it through the ajax request although I see the cookie set command in the developer tools. Iframe is not an option since I send the cookie data in a post request

Comment: You can't set a "cross-domain" cookie. Cookies are domain-bound and only the originating domain can set a cookie for that domain.

Comment: I know but I sent the ajax request to b.com and b.com told the browser to set a cookie for b.com. I don't see a security issue here. The same can be achieved with Iframe

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `withCredentials` to `true` for the XHR request:

```
$.ajax({
   url: a_cross_domain_url,
   xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
   }
});
```